# Starting a specific Firefox Profile with Selenium 3

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to upgrade from Selenium 2 to Selenium 3 but the old handling, which was pretty easy and fast doesn't work anymore (and the documentation is nonexisting as it seems)

This is the program at the moment and what I want is to open a Firefox driver with the profile: SELENIUM

Sadly it doesn't work and always shuts down with the Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' > occurred in WebDriver.dll
>
> Additional information: corrupt deflate stream

This is my program at the moment:

```
public Program()
{
    FirefoxOptions _options = new FirefoxOptions();
    FirefoxProfileManager _profileIni = new FirefoxProfileManager();
    FirefoxDriverService _service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\Programme\IMaT\Output\Release\Bin");
    _service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
    try
    {
        if ((_options.Profile = _profileIni.GetProfile("SELENIUM")) == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SELENIUM PROFILE NOT FOUND");
            _profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.type", 0); // disable proxy
            _profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new Exception("Firefox needs a Profile with \"SELENIUM\"");
    }
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(_service,_options,new System.TimeSpan(0,0,30));        
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("ld-hybrid.fronius.com");
    Console.Write("rtest");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new Program();
}
```

Without Loading the Profile it works with just new FirefoxDriver(_service) but the profile is mandatory.

In Selenium 2 I handled it with this code:

```
FirefoxProfileManager _profileIni = new FirefoxProfileManager();
// use custom temporary profile
try { 
    if ((_profile = _profileIni.GetProfile("SELENIUM")) == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SELENIUM PROFILE NOT FOUND");
        _profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.type", 0); // disable proxy
        _profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    }
}
catch
{
    throw new Exception("Firefox needs a Profile with \"SELENIUM\"");
}

_profile.SetPreference("intl.accept_languages", _languageConfig);
_driver = new FirefoxDriver(_profile);
```

Fast and simple, but as the Driver doesn't support a Constructor with service and profile I don't really know how to get this to work, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This exception is due to a bug in the .Net library. The code generating the Zip of the profile is failing to provide a proper Zip.

One way to overcome this issue would be to overload `FirefoxOptions` and use the archiver from .Net framework (System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive) instead of the faulty `ZipStorer`:

```
var options = new FirefoxOptionsEx();
options.Profile = @"C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ez3krw80.Selenium";
options.SetPreference("network.proxy.type", 0);

var service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\downloads", "geckodriver.exe");

var driver = new FirefoxDriver(service, options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

```
class FirefoxOptionsEx : FirefoxOptions {

    public new string Profile { get; set; }

    public override ICapabilities ToCapabilities() {

        var capabilities = (DesiredCapabilities)base.ToCapabilities();
        var options = (IDictionary)capabilities.GetCapability("moz:firefoxOptions");
        var mstream = new MemoryStream();

        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(mstream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true)) {
            foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Profile, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
                string name = file.Substring(Profile.Length + 1).Replace('\\', '/');
                if (name != "parent.lock") {
                    using (Stream src = File.OpenRead(file), dest = archive.CreateEntry(name).Open())
                        src.CopyTo(dest);
                }
            }
        }

        options["profile"] = Convert.ToBase64String(mstream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)mstream.Length);

        return capabilities;
    }

}
```

And to get the directory for a profile by name:

```
var manager = new FirefoxProfileManager();
var profiles = (Dictionary<string, string>)manager.GetType()
    .GetField("profiles", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .GetValue(manager);

string directory;
if (profiles.TryGetValue("Selenium", out directory))
    options.Profile = directory;
```

Comment: Thanks, i really was giving up on being able to use Selenium 3 ... Such a - i would say, Lowlevel Basic - that doesnt work is really a pain ... and finding nothing to this problem anywhere is even more.

With the overloaded version i need to know the Path of the SELENIUM Profile now, which is not really working for me, because we have multiple different Testing Computers with the profile, but on other locations and so on.

(new FirefoxProfileManager()).GetProfile("SELENIUM").ProfileDirectory when i try this the ProfileDirectory is always empty its only stored in a non public variable

Comment: @Dominik Lemberger, the path of each profile can be accessed by reflexion on an instance of `FirefoxProfileManager`: `var profiles = (Dictionary<string, string>)manager.GetType().GetField("profiles", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(manager);`.

Comment: How would this look in my case?
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfileManager().GetProfile("SELENIUM");
    var profiles = (Dictionary<string, string>)profile.GetType().GetField("ProfileDirectory", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(profile);
    options.Profile =

Cant seem to get it to work (ps: havent used reflexion ever before)

Comment: @Dominik Lemberger, have a look at the update to get the profiles by reflexion.

Comment: Thanks works like a charm - even tho i understand basically nothing what happens there :) 

Gonna try to read it now for the next few hours i guess haha

Comment: @FlorentB. I am still getting, you firefox profile couldn't be loaded error after implementing the same code. It opens up only after i click 'ok' manually and after the test is done getting 'firefox has stopped working' warning either. would you please take few mins to look into this?

Comment: @FlorentB. Here is the link to my code (can't write code in comment). It looks same as what you've here. please advice if i missed something. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3tWPIS9ivWkRG1uR0tjMUlfUEk/view

Comment: @FlorentB. great answer. Is there any way though to use the FirefoxProfile class with this? something like: options.Profile = new FirefoxProfile(@"C:\proflocation", false)