# Set custom profile directory for Firefox (Geckodriver)

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I have some profiles I would like to use in Firefox. 
I've tried to set a custom folder for the profiles but Firefox can't load the profile.
My code right now:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.AddArguments(@"user-data-dir=C:\SomeFolder\firefox" + @"\" + profilename + @"\");
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to utilise set the Profile property on the options class, e.g.

```
options.Profile = new FirefoxProfile("PATH_TO_PROFILE");
```

Sadly there seems to be an existing issue with this that many people have run in to. Luckily there is a brilliant answer to actually getting this to work, link is below. I would suggest following the answer to get your custom profile loaded.

[Starting a specific Firefox Profile with Selenium 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253372/starting-a-specific-firefox-profile-with-selenium-3)

Comment: It was helpful so I got an idea to find the solution with a little modification! Thanks!  
Final code:  
`FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
            options.AddArguments("-profile", @"C:\SomeFolder\firefox" + @"\" + profilename + @"\");
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that needs help with this for Python, it took me a while, but here it is

```
profile = "/home/{user}/.mozilla/firefox/{foldername}.default-release"
optns.add_argument(f"--profile={profile}")
dvr = webdriver.Firefox(options=optns)
```

P.S Any instances of Firefox need to be closed first